# Angular - Material - Testing - $mdSidenav

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, angularjs-material

First time that i'm writing a question on Stack ;)
I have a problem to test $mdSidenav (angular material component. see https://material.angularjs.org/). 
In my controller I have something like :

```
$scope.toggleRight = function() {
    $mdSidenav('right').toggle();
};
```

I want to test it. So in my test file I created, first of all, a mock of this object :

```
var $mdSidenav = function(test){
        return {
            toggle: function(){
                return true;
            }
        };
    };

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        createController = function () {
            return $controller('headerCtrl', {
                '$scope': $scope,
                '$mdSidenav': $mdSidenav
            });
        };
    }));
```

Then I'm trying to test it :

```
describe('toggleRight method', function(){
        beforeEach(function(){
            spyOn($mdSidenav('right'), 'toggle').and.callThrough();
        });

        it('Should toggleRight open/close', function(){
            $scope.toggleRight();
            expect($mdSidenav('right').toggle).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

    });
```

But karma send to me this error :

> Error: Expected a spy, but got Function.

I hope that someone could help me ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could try a different approach, use $provide and an anonymous module to inject the mock.

I'm using sinon here, but you can change to the appropriate Jasmine code:

```
var spy = sinon.spy();

beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
  $provide.value('$mdSidenav', function (v) {
    return {
      toggle: spy
    }
  });
}));
```

Then in the test:

```
sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy);
```

Comment: Ty for your reply ! But what is 'sinon' ? I don't understand... ;)

Comment: Sinonjs.org is just a differnet way to spy, stub or mock in Javascript. You can use Jasmine instead just replace the sinon usage with your Jasmine code.